# What kind of hacking attempt is this?

Tags: mysql, security, hacking

This past week, my traffic logs are showing many hits (usually with repeated tries) for a url from perhaps 30+ different ip addresses all over the world. This is not a url that should garner more than a single hit and it should only be accessed via a link from one page which contains rel="nofollow". The url calls a php whose sole purpose is to redirect to other websites based on the `id=` query parameter. The page's url is

```
mywebsite.com/linkredirect.php?id=434&site=www.creative-science.org.uk
```

The above link has also shown up in the logs in other forms:

```
/linkredirect.php?site=www.ausetute.com.au&id=266%25%27/**/aND/**/%278%25%27%3D%273
.. there were about 50 different iterations of this - which is attempting sql injection - but I can't figure out the purpose of it.

/linkredirect.php?id=434&site=www.premieresurgical.com
... this is an invalid link - the id=434 is valid but the "site=" query is invalid
```

I participate in Project Honeypot and some of the requests are Suspicious & Comment Spammer

The user agent appears to always be:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_3) AppleWebKit/536.28.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0.3 Safari/536.28.10
 ... or something similar
```

Perhaps unrelated, my error log shows two attempts at what appears a hack attempt at accessing one of my directories

```
[Tue Mar 04 21:32:12 2014] [error] [client 199.21.99.113] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /home/myusername/public_html/
```

What kind of attack is this and what is the purpose? Why would it repeatedly attempt access to the same link? Is my use of `id=` as a query parameter an invitation for malicious code to attempt to exploit?

Thanks for your input.

Comment: if I were you I'd ask the question on http://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Will do, thank you. I saw this type of question redirected to ServerFault from SO more than once. Too many sites to keep track of...

Comment: Why the mysql tag? looks more like a webserver log to me.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it has also been asked on security.SE, at http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/52742/what-kind-of-attack-is-this

Comment: MadHatter is correct. As per the advice, I posted the question at the link he referenced, thank you. The responses there answered the question and provided information regarding Google dorks and Blind SQL Injection. This question is closed and can either be deleted or left for others to follow the link.